# Validating the sorting functionality using Selenium (Java)

Tags: java, sorting, selenium

This is my first post for help. Please correct me if you see anything wrong with my post.

I am trying to validate the sorting functionality in a web page with Selenium script (using java). here are the details...

First I go to a User search results page with multiple pages. 
It has users with the details: user name, number of miles. 
There is a sort filter drop down with values: Values A-Z, Values Z-A, Miles Most, Miles Least, Newest Members, Oldest members . by default the sorting is newest members. 
Initially I just want to validate: Values A-Z, Values Z-A, Miles Most and Miles Least Since I could see those values in the search page.

Comment: I am not aware of selenium. But I don't see any question here :)

Comment: there are many options, I personally would use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

Comment: You need to provide some code. See [Ask].

Answer (score 1):

For someone who is looking to solve the same problem. Below code worked for me in validating the sorting of all the string values in a page

```
       //Declare Variables

            int eleCount;
            List<String> customerNameA = new ArrayList();
            List<String> customerNameB = new ArrayList();


            // Check for our Customer elements and count them.... replace xxx with your xpath
            assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("xxx")));
            elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xxx']"));

            eleCount = elements.size();   
            System.out.println("Element count: " + eleCount);

            for(int i = 2; i < eleCount; i++){ 
                //Capture the customer name values
                //replace xxx with your xpath & replace the value increments for each element in xpath with + i + 

                customerNameA.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xxx")).getText());
                System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xxx")).getText());
                customerNameB.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xxx")).getText());

            }
            Collections.sort(customerNameA);   

            for (int i=0;i<customerNameA.size();i++) {
                System.out.println("Customer Name from input: " + customerNameB.get(i)  +  "--Customer Name from sorted input: " + customerNameA.get(i));
                if (!(customerNameA.get(i).equals(customerNameB.get(i)))) {
                                System.out.println("Customer Names not sorted: " + i);
                                break;

                }
            }
        }
```